# The routing app coverage file is incorrectly formatted. Please refer to Apple's documentation

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-168.75,61.938950426660604],[-100.546875,-59.5343180010956],[181.40625,-56.94497418085159],[190.546875,73.02259157147301],[98.4375,83.02621885344846],[-63.28125,84.33698037639608],[-172.96875,76.18499546094715],[-168.75,61.938950426660604]]]}}]}
```

https://geojsonlint.com/ says it's a valid geojson. Why doesn't appstore connect console accept it? Can anyone help me with a valid geojson file?